# How to check if all lessons have been viewed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to define a method (complete) that returns true if a user has watched all lessons of a course. Right now the method only returns false even if all the lessons are viewed.

User model:

```
has_many :enrolments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :courses, through: :enrolments
has_many :views
has_many :lessons, through: :views

def enrol(course)
  courses << course
end

def enrolled?(course)
  courses.include?(course)
end

def view(lesson)
  lessons << lesson
end

def viewed?(lesson)
  lessons.include?(lesson)
end

def complete(course)
  if self.viewed?(course.lessons.all)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Lesson Model:

```
belongs_to :course
has_one_attached :file
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
has_many :views
has_many :users, through: :views
```

Course Model:

```
belongs_to :company
has_many :lessons, dependent: :destroy
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
has_many :enrolments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :enrolments
```

View Model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :lesson
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `viewed?` checks only for a single lesson, but you're passing a relation there.

For this case it's sufficient to compare arrays with lessons ids:

```rb
def complete(course)
  lessons.where(course: course).ids.sort == course.lessons.ids.sort
end
```

Comment: @RandomUser2002 try checking contents of these arrays, also try adding `.uniq` if there may be duplicates

Comment: I tried adding .uniq. The method still returns false

Comment: @RandomUser2002 updated, user's lessons can contain lessons from multiple courses